# Force a broader type for optional argument with more restrictive default value

Tags: ocaml

Is there a way to make optional argument `f` flexible enough to have type `'a -> 'b`, yet still make it default to `identity`, given that `identity` has type `'a -> 'a`?

[An earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267730/how-to-force-ocaml-to-infer-a-more-general-type/28268233#28268233) *begins* by stating my question, exactly:

> I want to define a function that accepts an optional argument which is
>   a function ('a -> 'b). The default value should be the identity, which
>   is actually ('a -> 'a), but i see no reason why it should not be
>   compatible with the more general ('a -> 'b).

However, the question then includes an example that exemplifies a narrower problem.  The answers to that question respond to the narrower problem.  Here is a simplistic illustration of the general issue:

```
# let g1 ~f x = f x;;
val g1 : f:('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b = <fun>
```

OK, that's the type I want.  But I'd like to `f` to default to an `identity` function. That should be possible, since `identity` has type `'a -> 'b` where `'b` is `'a`.  But it doesn't work:

```
# let g2 ?(f=identity) x = f x;;
val g2 : ?f:('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>
```

Adding a type specification on `identity` doesn't help:

```
# let g3 ?(f=(identity:'a -> 'b)) x = f x;;
val g3 : ?f:('b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'b = <fun>
```

EDIT: After I posted this question, I discovered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381126/ocaml-any-types-matching?rq=1), which really is a very close duplicate of my question.  So mark my question as a duplicate if you want.  However, the answers to that question imply that there is no good use for what I want to do, and that's not true.  Here are details:

The actual use case is a function that selects some elements from a list.  The optional `f` argument allows one to extract a bit of data from each element and use that data to decide whether to include that particular list element in the result.  When elements are selected by the whole element, `f` should be `identity`.  The actual function I'm trying to define is for lazy lists. Here's a simplified version for lists, with `L` as an alias for `List`:

```
let select ?(accessor=identity) keys vals =
  let rec sel ks vs =
    if ks = [] || vs = [] then []
    else let k, v = L.hd ks, L.hd vs in
         let v_key = accessor v in
         if k = v_key then v::(sel (L.tl ks) (L.tl vs))
         else if k > v_key then sel ks (L.tl vs) (* let vs catch up *)
         else sel (L.tl ks) vs                   (* let ks catch up *)
  in sel keys vals
```

Simple use:

```
# let vs = Batteries.List.range 1 `To 100;;
# let ks = [4; 10];;
# select ks vs;;
- : int list = [4; 10]
```

The more general use is when elements of `ks` are, say, records with a key field that's an integer.  Then the `accessor` function would map from the record type to `int`.

(Yes, I know that the use of `hd` and `tl` is a bit unusual.  It translates into the lazy list context better.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OCaml simply does not support this. You cannot write a function with a type that is refined depending on whether an optional argument has been passed.

Unlike some the answers in the linked question, I agree that this is a reasonable thing to want to do. Indeed, typing things like Common Lisp's sequence functions (with `:key` and `:test`) seems to require something like this. However, OCaml is not a language in which it can be done.

The most reasonable approach is probably to write two functions, one of which takes an accessor as non-optional argument, and the other which supplies `identity` as that argument:

```
let g f x = f x

let g_default x = g identity x
```

This is only a little clumsy, and you do not need to implement the logic in `g` twice. However, applying this approach to combinations of more than one optional argument will become ugly.

Comment: Thanks gsg.  I am curious about why this can't be done, but that's a different question than the one I asked.  The answer may have to do with subtleties of the OCaml type system.  I suspect that this sort of thing is a lot simpler in Common Lisp since it's dynamically typed.

Comment: The reason is actually really simple. Optional arguments are exactly expanded into pattern matching something of type `option`. Try to write a function that does the specialization you want with an argument of type `_ option`, and you will see that you can't do that either.

Answer (score 3):

I think the way to look at this is to imagine what type your function would have. You seem to be asking for this type:

```
?f:('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b
```

However, this doesn't capture the idea that when you leave out the optional parameter, the type reverts to `'a -> 'a`.

Instead, what this type says is that if you leave out the optional parameter, you have a function of type `'a -> 'b`. But there is no well-formed function of type `'a -> 'b`. This can only be the type of a function that never returns (or similar).

My take on this is that the OCaml type system can't represent the function you want, even though it does make sense.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey.  However, a function that actually has the type `'a -> 'b` isn't what's required by the use case.  The type of `f` in `g1` is `'a -> 'b`, and the type of `accessor` in the longer example would be `'a -> 'b` if I changed the parameter to `~accessor`.  That just means that this argument can be any function compatible with what the function has to do inside the outer function.  If what I'm asking for can't be done, it seems to be simply an arbitrary limitation of OCaml.  (Or not really arbitrary: I'm sure there are reasons for it.)

Comment: Yes, what I'm saying is that there's no type in OCaml for what you want. As far as I can see. And you can only define functions in OCaml that have OCaml types.

Comment: I can't do what I want in OCaml, but it doesn't seem to me to be correct to describe it as a case in which "there is no type ... for what" I want.   `'a -> 'b`  is an OCaml type, and it's unproblematic to define functions with non-optional parameters that have that type.  `identity` has that type, as well as the more specific type `'a -> 'a`, so I can pass `identity` as an argument to such a function: `let g f x = f x;; g identity 2 = 2;; - : int = 2`.  Yet I cannot give `identity` as a default value for an optional parameter whose type is `'a -> 'b`, even though it's an instance of that type.

Comment: Give a type for your function as a whole, not just for the parameter.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you were saying.  Then I guess I should say that it's ... interesting that there are functions with type `('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b`, but no function with type `?f:('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b`, even though the only difference is that in the second case the first argument is optional.  Maybe it's an artifact of syntax?  The only syntax that allows you to define an optional argument that doesn't have an `option` type requires a default function, whose most specific type is treated as the parameter's type.

Comment: Wait--it can be done.  There is such a type.  It's just that it's useless.  I paid closer attention to your answer.  The default is useless, so you might as well not make the argument optional: `let rec forever x = forever x;; let g ?(f=forever) x = f x;;
val g : ?f:('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b = <fun>`.  I didn't understand the remarks about this in the other answer until now.  (I still think it would be useful to be able to specify a broader type than the most specific type of the default argument with defaults such as `identity`, but not much more useful than what gsg suggested.)

Comment: “this doesn't capture the idea that when you leave out the optional parameter, the type reverts to 'a -> 'a.” → This is enlightening! The following sentence however, “there is no well-formed function of type `'a -> 'b`”, is irrelevant; plus, there seems to be confusion between `'a -> 'b` where type variables are free, tied to other occurrences, placeholders for ground types, and `'a 'b. 'a -> 'b` where they are universally quantified. There is no interesting function of type `'a 'b. 'a -> 'b` (except `raise`), but there are tons of interesting functions whose type has shape `'a -> 'b`.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question while I was asking myself the exact same question and I found a solution that is a bit dirty but yet working:

You can't do it on the function level but on the result one:

```
external identity : 'a -> 'b = "%identity"

let to_array ?(f = identity) s = Array.init (String.length s) (fun i -> f s.[i])
```

And then when you use it without any argument:

```
let c : char array = to_array "abc";;
val c : char array = [|'a'; 'b'; 'c'|]
```

Obviously, this can lead to some really bad behaviour:

```
# let c : string array = to_array "abc";;

Process OCaml segmentation fault
```

So I wouldn't advise doing it but it's not impossible

Comment: The secret is that `external` trusts whatever type you write, so this is essentially the same as using `Obj.magic` to force the default value to a more general type than it really has. In other words, you can just do `let apply ?(f = Obj.magic (fun x -> x)) x = f x`. Then, either you call it with a non-default value and everything is fine (`apply f:succ 42` shows `- : int = 43`), or you leave the default and then the result’s type appears more general than it really is (`apply 42` shows `- : 'a = <poly>`), and it’s up to you to constrain the result to the right type or bad things will happen.

Comment: So, why do you say “You can't do it on the function level but on the result one”?

Comment: You can actually write `?(f = Obj.magic)` since `Obj.magic` is `"%identity` but I rather be sure that my function will always be the identity ;-)
I say that you can't do it on the function level meaning that the expected behaviour is only possible when you give the proper type when executing it rather than when writing it. Poor choice of words, sorry